# php connect from webserver to ddns localserver database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm unable to connect my webserver to my localhost, i can make the connection on mysql workbench on "server.ddns.net:3306" but on connect.php i can't.

My connect file:

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'pass');

$sql = "SELECT DDNS FROM table ORDER BY tableid DESC LIMIT 1";
foreach ($connect->query($sql) as $row) { $host = $row['DDNS']; }

if($host != NULL){
    try {
       $connect2= new PDO('mysql:host=server.ddns.net;dbname=database', 'user', 'pass');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
       die();
    }
}
```

And it returns:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server.ddns.net' (111 "Connection refused")

Comment: You forgot to close quotes in your first line.

Comment: @svgrafov this about the error not about the code ty anyway

Comment: Than add actual code that you need help with. Code in your question should not even run.
You must have missed this nice article : [MCVE]